# Energy cost of calculation in non-quasistatic limit

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, electronics

The [Landauer principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer's_principle) puts a limit to the cost of irreversible computations, namely that an operation that erases 1bit of information has a minimal energy cost of $E=k_B T \ln 2$. 
This limit is stated in the quasistatic case, when the computation takes a very long time to happen. [This arcticle](http://advances.sciencemag.org/content/2/3/e1501492.full) used a twenty minute period to erase their bit, much much slower that the rate at which our current memories or processors work.

The question is for faster, more realistic processes, what is the limit? What is the limit at 1MHz? at 1GHz? Can we use basic thermodynamics arguments, [like here](http://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.10023) to find a frequency dependance to the landauer energy cost?

As the current cost of calculations is 6 orders of magnitude above the Landauer limit, my wider question is how low can we go? are we much higher because of the inefficiency of our computing devices or are we close to the actual limit at the GHs frequencies we use?

Thanks for your help.